# base64 String decoding using Apache Commons

Tags: java, base64, apache-commons

I am trying to decode one of my files from dropbox. Using one of the post in this forum

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;
String base64String = getFileResults.get_Response();//returns a file content in base64
String result = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(base64String));
```

But the Netbeans keeps telling me that the decodeBase64() does not take string, but the API says that it takes a string in base 64.

What am i missing?

Comment: You're missing a `)`.

Comment: I am sorry for posting this...I cannot believe I missed that. Thank you.

Comment: nevermind, it still gives the same error

Comment: What version of apache commons are you using? And please post the full error message.

Comment: Compile Error: decode64 in Base64 cannot be applied to given types. Required: byte[] found:String

Comment: how do i know what version i am using for appache commons? I know that I am running java 1.7

Comment: Check the jar you've added to your build path.

Comment: I just added the codec binary src and bin 1.9 but it still gives me error.

Comment: Do you have your own `String` class in the same package?

Comment: No I do not have my own String class.

Comment: Then Netbeans is having some serious problems. I recommend trying with a new project to see if it at least compiles.

Comment: I mean the import statement gives no error. However, I am not sure which jar i added for this appache commons. where am i supposed to get it from

Comment: You can download the binary [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec).

Comment: You are right NetBeans is going crazy. Eclipse it works but not netbeans

Comment: Code is fine for commons.codec version 1.8 and 1.6, but fails for version 1.3. Anyway there is a method getBytes() in String class, could be used to get byte array of the response String.

Comment: I just have a general question then. I had downloaded zip folders from apache. What are these zip folders then for?

Answer (score 1):

Try `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64String)` available in Java SE.

Answer (score -1):

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

...
File file = new File( "path" );
byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64( "base64" );
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile( file, bytes );
```

Comment: *"Code-only"* answers should be avoided, as they don't explain why the OP's code (if any), strategy or concept are wrong, or why the answer's are right. Providing an explanation allows for not only the OPA, but also to *all readers* to understand what's going on; including people who are new to the programming languages and/or APIs being used, and who might not be familiar with the code, and thus might not find it intuitive (even if you do). In other words, remember that the *why* is far more important than the *what*, specially in answers.